# Creating Self signed certificate for tomcat 6

Tags: rhel, ssl, certificates, tomcat

I am trying to configure self signed certificate for our `tomcat` server. For that initially I created the keystore certificate file using `keytool` .

The command I tried for this is

```
keytool -genkey -alias example -keyalg RSA -keystore /home/zaman/certs/keystorefile.key
chmod 600 /home/zaman/certs/keystorefile.key
```

Then uncommneted the SSL connector tag in server.xml to add reference to keystore file

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true" keystoreFile="/home/zaman/certs/keystorefile.key" keystorePass="test123"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

After this I restarted tomcat server , but cannot access tomcat link `(https://localhost:8443)` using https. Nothing is seen in log file .

```
$ netstat -apn | grep 8443
tcp        0      0 :::8443                     :::*                        LISTEN      25759/java
```

What I am missing to make https work for tomcat using self signed certificate?

Comment: Is http://localhost:8443 a typo? Did you mean `https://localhost:8443` ?
Please paste the output of `netstat -apn | grep 8443`

Comment: It was typo . I edited my original query with necessary as you requested

Comment: Can you put `address="127.0.0.1"` somewhere inside the SSL connector tag and restart tomcat and try?

Comment: tried but no luck...

Comment: What port is the non-https tomcat running? Is it 8080 or 80? Can you paste the netstat out with that port?

Comment: It is 8080 and no issues with 8080.                            $ netstat -tlpn | grep 8080

tcp        0      0 :::8080                     :::*                        LISTEN      26270/java